# watching an observable on valueChanges in a dynamic form values are lost when a new group is created

Tags: angular

so I have a little issue here...
I have my observable that watches for the value change of the accountId in the form and then gets the list of messages associated with that account.

```
this.accountMessagesDataSource$ = this.piForm.get('accountId').valueChanges
    .switchMap(query => this.pitching.getAccountMessage(query));
```

this is then used in the form.

```
<div formArrayName="_messages"
    *ngFor="let row of _messages.controls; let i=index;"
    class="mb-3">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-11">
                    <select class="btn-underline-primary btn-block"
                        (change)="messageSelect($event.target.value, i)">
                        <option value="" selected="">Choose from list</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let message of accountMessagesDataSource$ | async"
                            [value]="message.accountMessageId">
                                {{ message.message }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-1" (click)="deleteRow(i, '_messages')">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the catch here is that when I fire the method to add a new row...

```
<button type="button"class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-2"
    (click)="addNewRow('_messages')">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

a new row is inserted, however the  loop is not populated now I noticed if i go back in the form and re-select the account then all the select boxes are populated I'm certain this is because the observable is watching for valueChanges my thoughts here are to maybe take this and map it to another property since I only need the results once if the account changes...thoughts?

Comment: Aren't you missing a subscribe there?

Comment: @rrd the async pipe subscribes and unsubscribes...

Answer (score 0):

When you add a row, the whole array is redraw in the UI.

To avoid that behaviour (and it's a good practice for perfs anyway) you should add a `trackBy` function on your `*ngFor`:

HTML:

```
*ngFor="let row of _messages.controls; trackBy: trackById; let i=index;"
```

TS:

```
class YourComponent {
  ...

  trackById(index: number, item: YourTipeItem) {
    return item.id; // or whatever that is unique on your item
  }

  ...
}
```